# Connect with a database over the LAN

Tags: mysql, windows, database, delphi, lan

How to connect with a database over the LAN?

I have only the name of the computer.

Comment: I think we need a bit more data to help you. How are you connecting, do you only know the name of the computer (and not the database, port etc), and why can't you connect with the data you have/know now?

Comment: Which database?  What connection technology are you using?

Comment: To connect to the database you'll need to know the IP address or hostname of the computer where MySQL is installed.

Comment: MySql, Port 3306 using Delphi over windows LAN. 

I have access to the computer that has the DB, but do not know your IP. The IP is dynamic.

Comment: pygorex, how can I set the hostname to be visible over LAN?

Answer (score 2):

You must add your host to the '**user**' system table to allow your computer connect remotely to the MySql DB.

You can use instructions like [http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/...](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) to do this.

Comment: I change localhost to localhost2 and with telnet in the same computer I tried "telnet localhost2 3306" and I got
"Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused"

Comment: Have you root password to the DB? Try to change host 'localhost' to '%' in the 'user' table and restart mysql.

P.S. It's not good idea for the production environment, but you can try this method to overpass your issue.

Comment: try to turn off the firewall or/and your antivirus protection